# Cannot convert object to np.int64 with Numpy

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 3 columns with the following dtypes:

```
df.info()
tconst       object
directors    object
writers      object
```

Please see the data itself:

[image]

Now, I have to change the column tconst to dtype:int64. I tried this code but it throws an error:

```
df = pd.read_csv('title.crew.tsv',
                   header=None,sep='\t', 
                   encoding= 'latin1',
                   names = ['tconst', 'directors','writers'], 
                   dtype={'tconst': np.int64,'directors':np.int64})
```

**Error 1:ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'tconst' 

Error:TypeError: Cannot cast array from dtype('O') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'**

What is going wrong here?

Comment: We would need a sample of your data csv to help you.

Comment: @Tomothy32 sorry, I just added it.

Comment: I don't see any integers in that tsv display.  All numbers are preceeded by letters like 'tt' and 'nm'.  They are `object` in the dataframe because they are loaded as strings.  They can't be converted to integers, at least not in their current form.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion problem here is parameter `header=None` which is used for read `file` with no `csv` header.

Solution is remove it, because in file is first row header, which is conveterted to columns names of `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('title.crew.tsv',
                   sep='\t', 
                   encoding= 'latin1')
```

Another problem is `tt` and `nm` prefix in columns, so cannot be converted to integers.

Solution is:

```
df['tconst'] = df['tconst'].str[2:].astype(int)
```

Comment: I just removed the header=None and re-ran it. Still, same error unfortunately.

Comment: @Tini - Are data confidental?

Comment: @Tini - Is possible share it or add link for download?

Comment: @Tini - In some rows are multiple values separated by `,` e.g. in row `8` is `nm0005690,nm0374658`. Do you need create 2 rows in data? `tt0000007  nm0374658         \N` and `tt0000007  nm0005690         \N` ?